# 'PFObject' is not a subtype of 'Post' - Swift Error

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

So I'm fairly new to Swift and I've been trying to follow along with a tutorial I found on Youtube. Its going well, however, I've ran into an error that I can't seem to find any solution online. So I keep getting this error: "`'PFObject' is not a subtype of 'Post'`" from the following code:

```
var posts : [Post] = []
var postDates = [String]()

func loadData() {
        var query = PFQuery(className: "Post")
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(post: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?)-> Void in

            if (error == nil) {
                if let posts = posts as? [PFObject] {
                    for post in posts {
                        self.postDates.append(posts["createdAt"] as! String)
                    }

                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            } else {
                // is an error
            }

        }
    }
```

The error occurs at: `if let posts = posts as? [PFObject]`

This is the video I've been following along to: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L3VQ0TE_fjU

If anyone can help explain whats going on, I'd very much appreciate it.

Comment: Additionally, the portion of code above starts at the beginning of the video.

Comment: Where is that error supposed to occur? I see no reference to `Post` anywhere. Additionally there is no variable definition for `posts`.

Comment: Sorry, the error occurs at: if let posts = posts as? [PFObject]

Comment: You named the variable 'post' instead of 'posts' in the callback parameters. You just made a typo

Comment: Ahhhh, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For those having trouble in the future, here was my solution:

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(posts: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?)-> Void in
```